# How to print Loop like this format i already tryout you can see my solution but its not working

Tags: javascript

how to print loop exactily like 3 section i and i^2 and i^3. dont use any function just tell me is this posssible? if possible then how?

```
i    i^2   i^3
 0    0     0
 1    1     1
 2    4     8
 3    9     27
 4    16    64
 5    25    125
 6    36    216
 7    49    343
 8    64    512
 9    81    729
 10   100   1000
```

here is my solution. i am new in Programming.

```
for(let i=0; i <= 10; i++){
    document.write(`i${i} i^2 ${i**2} i^3 ${i**3}`);
    document.write("</br>");
};
```

Comment: Your function is almost there. Just print your "header" line before your start the for loop (`document.write("i i^2 i^3");`) and then in your for loop: ``document.write(`i${i} ${i**2} ${i**3}`);``

Comment: Why can't we use functions? You want a table. And [you probably don't want to use `document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write).

Comment: thank u so much Cully its working now.